# Running Cron Job Even When Not Required

Tags: cron, pm2

I have a Cron Job scheduled to execute a command a few times a day. There are cases where the cron job isn't needed but will automatically run. If that happens the following error message shows:

```
PM2 [ERROR] Script already launched, add -f option to force re execution
```

Note: The Cron Job runs PM2 in reference to a script.

Is there any negative effect to having the cron job run even if the script is already running?

Please provided detailed information or references. Not just your opinion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what detailed information or references there could be for a situation like this. It's not like someone commissions a study to look at this.

Assuming your command is intelligent enough to only allow one execution at a time (which appears to be the case judging by the error message you posted) then the only ill effect is a few CPU clock cycles (I think).

Comment: What I meant by detailed information or references is I didn't want an answer that was `I think it...` Your answer is fine.

Comment: Ha! => Made me smile.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid erroneous error messages by writing a wrapper script that is run from cron instead.  Inside the wrapper script, only run your job if it is not already running by querying the process table.

Assuming ksh, here's a snippet (I'm a tad rusty so syntax may need to be tweaked):

```
# Running will be non-zero if no match found
running=$(ps|grep MY_PROGRAM)
if [[ "$running" -gt 0 ]]; then
  # run your program
else
  # log its already running
fi
```

Comment: The question is-is that even necessary? It appears the command itself is basically already doing that. I guess it depends on how much CPU and RAM it eats up before it throws the error. I doubt that's much though since whoever made the command was thoughtful enough to already check for this condition.

Comment: Can you provide examples? This area I have no information on. Also would that work on a shared hosting environment as I came across various scripts that would not work on shared hosting?

Comment: @mason I would have to argue it's bad practice to allow non-errors to be created when it could be avoided.  The benefit will come when you or more likely the person maintaining this behind you a year from now can review logs when troubleshooting and not have to chase down non-errors. It is much better and cleaner to catch the error and log what is really going on instead. Seeing something like "cronjob: starting MY_PROGRAM - already running" tells you what happened without having to chase an error message down just to find its a non-error. Can you tell I used to work support:  :-)

Comment: I would argue that apart from saying `Error` the command is already doing just that. Handy script for commands that don't already do this though!

Comment: @Lynda I'm afraid I do not know about a shared hosting environment.

Comment: @mason The error has the string "ERROR" in it.  This may cause monitoring scripts to see that and raise flags when indeed it is not an error.  I am playing the devil's advocate, having had to deal with this very thing in production.  Pager going off at 03:00 because of non-errors logged as "ERROR"s!  Catch non-errors early and enjoy a good night's sleep.  heh

Comment: Granted the original program should not log the fact that it is already running as an error.  It's up to your requirements and environment to decide whether that condition is really an error or not.  It should return a unique return code for the condition and let the wrapper program query that and decide (by you) what is the appropriate action.

Comment: `ps` with no arguments is likely to miss the process. With options, the `ps` process may find itself. `man ps` before trying this approach.

Comment: @Keith oops last comment not complete should be: Right do: "ps |grep [m]y_program" which matches "my_program" but not "grep [m]y_program".

Comment: @Gary_W: The behavior of `ps` varies considerably. On my Linux system, `ps` with no arguments only shows processes owned by the current user *and* associated with the current terminal -- which would miss any processes invoked by cron.